# AJAX post won’t do checkbox array with PHP Foreach Loop

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So I have been struggling on this for sometime and can not figure it out. I have a form of checkboxes each with an id=“athlete[]” and a class=“togglea”. Here is an example of a few of my checkboxes (I have hundreds)

```
<input type="checkbox" class="togglea" id="1" value="1" name="athlete[]" onchange="updateSum()">
<input type="checkbox" class="togglea" id="2" value="2" name="athlete[]" onchange="updateSum()">
<input type="checkbox" class="togglea" id="3" value="3" name="athlete[]" onchange="updateSum()">
<input type="checkbox" class="togglea" id="4" value="4" name="athlete[]" onchange="updateSum()">
<input type="checkbox" class="togglea" id="5" value="5" name="athlete[]" onchange="updateSum()">
```

I have this ajax script to post an array of checkboxes without refreshing page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function(){
   var athlete = [];
   $('.togglea').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
             athlete.push($(this).val());
        }
   });
   athlete = athlete.toString();
   $.ajax({
        url:"dataget.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{athlete:athlete},
        success:function(data){
             $('#result').html(data);
        }
   });
});
});`
```

And then I have this PHP script inside of the dataget.php file:

```
if(isset($_POST["athlete"]))
{
  // Counting number of checked checkboxes.
  $checked_count = $_POST['athlete'];
  echo "You have selected ".$checked_count."";
  foreach($checked_count as $selected) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM olympics WHERE athlete_id = '$selected'";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo $row["athlete_name"];
  }
  } else { echo "0 results"; }
  }

}
```

I cannot seem to understand why in my ForEach php loop in the dataget.php will not work. If I remove the for each loop and change **athlete_id ='1'** for example it does indeed pull the data from athlete #1 so I know it does connect to the database.

Hopefully you guys can help me figure this out because I can not figure out why my Foreach loop will not cycle through and pull all the data out.

**P.S. $Check_count does pull all the data selected into an array separated by commas so i KNOW I am posting the checkboxes correctly.**

Comment: Can you add the Html code? You need to add  name="athlete[]" to your checkboxes.

Comment: @davidev I have added a snippet of the HTML code. The checkboxes do have the name=athlete[]. It does pull the data correctly hence the $checked_count where it dislpays the id's of checked checkboes, it will just not work in the foreach loop

Comment: Same result when you use foreach($_POST["athlete"] as $selected) ?

Comment: Is there a error when you run it like above?

Comment: @davidev I have tried and still does not work;/ Im not sure what the issue is

Comment: Okay, any PHP error messages?

Comment: @davidev None. It simply does just display more than one athlete. However, If i remove the foreach loop then place athlete_id=$counted_check and select one checkbox it does show the 1 checked box and all data inside the mysql table with that athletes's id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208293/discussion-between-davidev-and-xavier-gallo).

Comment: `$_POST["athlete"]` is a string with comma separated values, not an array.

Comment: athlete = athlete.toString(); is creating a string, not an array, you need to explode athlete parameter into an array if you want to use this payload so $checked_count = explode(',', $_POST['athlete']);